# How to find the selected list item in the Connected Sorted List

Tags: jquery, list, drag-and-drop

i am using the Connected sort able lists to implement the drag and drop functionality between two list boxes. how do i find the selected element (or list items present in the 2nd list box after the drag) and send it to the code behind so that i can save it to the database. i am using Linqdatasource for database operation. my java script is-

```
$(function () {
        $("#Setter,#Getter").sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable",
            recieve: function (e, ui)
            {

                var item = (this).valueOf("Section");

            }
        });
```

and my lists are as follows-

```
<asp:ListView ID="Listview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1"   >
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    Unallocated Sections <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="SetterCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <ul class="sortable" draggable="true" id="Setter" style="overflow: scroll; empty-cells: hide; height: 500px; width: 200px; border: solid  1px; background: #b6b6b6;"  >
        <li id="Li1" runat="server" draggable="true"    >
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" id-="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </li>

    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li id="Li2" runat="server" title="Drag to Allocate sections" >
                        <%# Eval("Section")%>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </td>

        <td>

            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server" DataSourceID ="LinqDataSource6">
                <HeaderTemplate><ul class="sortable" draggable="true" id="Getter" style="overflow: scroll; empty-cells: hide; height: 500px; width: 200px; border: solid  1px; background: #b6b6b6;"  ></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li id ="lI2" runat ="server">
                       <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, ("Section"))%>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

       </td>
       </tr>

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

$(function () {

```
        $("Getter,Setter").sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable",
            update: function (event, ui) {
                alert("New position: " + (ui.item.index() + 1));
                alert(ui.item.text());

            }
        });
    });
```